# JAVA ZipFile entries() method doesn't see directories

Tags: java, zip

I'm working on digital documents and digital signatures and I've stumbled upon a problem.

Input: documentX.adoc - zip file with files and folders inside.

I need to get all the content in the input file - a list of dirs and files.

What do I do:

```
ZipFile adocFile = new ZipFile(documentXFileName);
ArrayList <String> adocFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
Enumeration <? extends ZipEntry> entries;
entries = adocFile.entries();
for (entries = adocFile.entries(); entries.hasMoreElements();)
{
    adocFiles.add(entries.nextElement().getName());
}
```

I've tried to create ArrayList < ZipEntry > and add ZipEntries instead of names - still nothing. Maybe there is some other way? Strange thing is, that ZipEntry has a .isDirectory() method...

Thanks for help,
Martin

Comment: Have you checked the zip file to make sure the directories actually got created in it?

Comment: Your code looks OK to me.  Perhaps open up the zip file (based on the given filename) in some external zip tool and just double-check that the file does contain entries?  If that works, it could be an issue with a format that the Java implementation doesn't support, but I really don't know...

Comment: Yes, the directories are there. I can browse zip file (with Far Manager), I see all dirs and I can extract it to see the dirs too.

Comment: BTW, Andrzej Doyle, thanks for correcting the post.

Answer (score 12):

From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#isDirectory()):

> A directory entry is defined to be one whose name ends with a '/'.

It is not necessary to store directories in a ZIP file - they are optional entries. It is possible to store a byte sequence with the path `foo/bar.txt` without an entry called `foo`. Zip tools may provide the illusion that such things exist within the archive even if they don't.